# CSS effect on an element created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

first time poting here :)

Right so, I'm working on a project in my college where I have to create
notes as "task notes" and these notes are supposed to 
appear in fade-in each time I create one and join an array.

```
.note_input {
    height:255px;
    width:200px;
    background-image:url('../img/notebg.png');
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-left:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    animation: fadein 2s; 
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; 
}
    @keyframes fadein {
        from {
            opacity:0;
        }
        to {
            opacity:1;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
        from {
            opacity:0;
        }
        to {
            opacity:1;
        }
    }
```

that's the note CSS

Now my JavaScript is something like this :

```
function Note(){
    notes_p = JSON.parse(notes_j);
    var note_d = "<div>";
    for (var i = 0 ; i < notes.length ; i++) {
        note_d += "<span class='note_input'>" + "<div class='flow' ><p>"+notes[i].input+"</p></div></br>" + "</br>" +"Time:  "+ notes[i].time + "</br>" +"Date:  "+ notes[i].date;
        note_d +=  "</span>";
        };
    note_d += "</div>";
    document.getElementById("note_div").innerHTML = note_d;
    console.log(notes_p);
}
```

NOW this works as it creates a note in fade BUT the following note appears in fade as well, meaning the array gets run over..
Any solution?
I want a single array to appear in fade each time and I know it has to do with its id but no direction.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/c4k1rrge/

Actually It really doesn't matter about IDs. What you would need to do is to apply an animation programatically to a note using JavaScript. You should **not** have any animation initially applied to the note beforehand.

You can add an animation like any style:

`ele.style.animation = "animation duration etc...";`

Also, this is just preference, but if your animation requires a default parameter for its starting point you can just leave it out. Where in your code you have a from{} and to{}, in the below example I'm just using to{} because 0 opacity is set as default by the css.

As an example:

css:

```
.note {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
 let arr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.note'));

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    arr[i].style.animation = "fadein 2s";
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

In the above example(found here: https://jsfiddle.net/c4k1rrge/)  it staggers the notes. I wasn't sure if that was something you had requested (Sorry, I had a hard time understanding your wording).

Comment: My bad for the wording, I'm writing this as I am working on it.
So I apologize.

Comment: My bad for the wording, I'm writing this as I am working on it.
So I apologize.

Let me rephrase.
I want to create a note in an array using JS+CSS and I want the note to appear in fade in.
I am supposed to use CSS3 as part of the project, so transition.
Now It works with the code I posted but everytime I create a new note the whole array reappears in fade...

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating the entire list by using `.innerHTML`. This makes the browser start the animation on all the note items each time you make an update. Instead, use `HTMLElement.appendChild(HTMLElement)`.

For example...

```
var generatedEl = document.createElement('div');
generatedEl.innerHTML = note_d;
document.getElementById("note_div").appendChild(generatedEl);
```

Comment: Wait wait wait ! i am so confused because of this project.
if I copy this code ^ and implement it in, should it work?

Comment: If you replace `document.getElementById("note_div").innerHTML = note_d;` with the code above, I believe it should work, yes.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, no. You will need a few other changes since your loop to create the entire list is in the Note() function

Comment: Yeah I tried it doesn't work it just creates another div and the whole array all over while leaving the previous created on the page

Comment: what else can I do to create the notes if not by using a for loop?

Comment: I know you're just learning, so this may be very difficult to read, but see if this makes any sense...
https://jsfiddle.net/kx6q4nqd/

(Click the list to add another list item)

Comment: Don't be afraid of the `(function() { ... })();` lines in that fiddle, btw. I'm just trying to contain variables.

Comment: Yeah it's kinda hard, and even so it doesn't help since I need to create these items using both CSS JS HTML for loops and make sure they go into an array.

Comment: Maybe it does help but I'm not good enough to understand that...:(

Comment: Can you work around that?..please.

Also? THANKS SO MUCH for trying to help this much

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't do someone's coding for them. But, you've shown some solid effort and I can see you're struggling. Merry Christmas - https://jsfiddle.net/640kxd0d/4/. Hope that helps!

Comment: First of all thank you so much dude ! I've got it working with help from another user :D !